# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer ese ejercicio, pero al tratar de convertir cada lista en una lista de numeros, me sale ese error:

Este es el ejercicio.

En un curso de programación, no diremos en
cuál, el profesor hace 12 talleres, con 9, 11, 12,
8, 12, 9, 11, 8, 11, 10, 9, y 10 ejercicios
respectivamente. La calificación del curso se
calcula de la siguiente manera. Cada taller tiene
una calificación individual que es igual a la
cantidad de ejercicios resueltos correctamente
sobre la cantidad de ejercicios del taller. Eso
multiplica por 5 y se redondea a una cifra
decimal. Luego se toman esas 12
calificaciones, se promedian y se redondea de
nuevo.

Dado el registro de la cantidad de ejercicios resueltos en cada taller por N estudiantes,
así como su correspondiente documento de identidad ¿harías un programa para calcular
la nota definitiva y mostrar el resultado ordenado de manera ascendente según el
documento?

Para ello ten recuerda que primero se calcula la calificación de cada taller, se redondea,
luego se calcula la calificación final y se redondea de nuevo, en ambos casos a una cifra
decimal. Si solo haces uno de los redondeos, es posible que los resultados no coincidan
exactamente. También ten en cuenta que debes considerar el documento del estudiante
como número no como texto, para que el ordenamiento coincida

Entrada

La entrada comienza con una línea que contiene la cantidad N de estudiantes. Luego
siguen N líneas, cada una con los datos separados entre sí por una coma y un espacio
en blanco: el documento de identidad y la cantidad de ejercicios resueltos por cada
estudiante en los 12 talleres (en el orden correspondiente).

Salida

La salida contener N líneas, cada una con el documento y la calificación final, separados
entre sí por un espacio en blanco y ordenados ascendentemente por documento.

Ejemplo de entrada
4
(888888, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)

(555555, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)

(777777, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7)

(111111, 9, 11, 12, 8, 12, 9, 11, 8, 11, 10, 9, 10)

Ejemplo de salida

(111111 5.0)
(555555 2.6)
(777777 3.6)
(888888 4.09

pdt: puse cada entrada y cada salida entre parentesis para que no haya confusion

```
N=int(input())

tablaEstudiantes= []

for i in range(N):
   elemento= input()
   elemento2= elemento.split(",")
   tablaEstudiantes.append([int(a) for a in str(elemento2)])
print(tablaEstudiantes)
```

esta es la parte que llevo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en el uso de `str()` en esta línea:

```
tablaEstudiantes.append([int(a) for a in str(elemento2)])
```

Es un error pues `elemento2` es una lista

```
[888888, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

y cuando aplicas `str()` deja de serlo y pasa a ser **un** string

```
"[888888, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]"
```

Cuando ejecutas el `for`, estas iterando sobre los caracteres del string, no sobre los valores representados.

**Solución**

Elimina el `str()`.

En esta demo puse explícitamente los valores para no tener que digitar tanto:

```
#N=int(input())

N = 4
lineas = ["888888, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8",
          "555555, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5",
          "777777, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7",
          "111111, 9, 11, 12, 8, 12, 9, 11, 8, 11, 10, 9, 10"]

tablaEstudiantes= []

for i in range(N):
   elemento= lineas[i]
   elemento2= elemento.split(",")
   tablaEstudiantes.append([int(a) for a in elemento2])
print(tablaEstudiantes)
```

produce:

```
[[888888, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], [555555, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [777777, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [111111, 9, 11, 12, 8, 12, 9, 11, 8, 11, 10, 9, 10]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Estás cometiendo un error al pasar las entradas de str a int para poder hacer operaciones.
Prueba este cambio:

```
N=int(input())

tablaEstudiantes= []

for i in range(N):
   elemento= input()
   elemento2= elemento.split(",")
   elemento2=list(map(int,elemento2))
   tablaEstudiantes.append(elemento2)
print(tablaEstudiantes)
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Aunque la respuesta pueda ser correcta le hace falta explicar el motivo por el cual es una solución válida. Por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega detalles y una explicación.